# Квадратные элементы в css grid

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-grid

Имеется grid в три колонки.

```css
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

Необходимо сделать элементы квадратными на **всех разрешениях** без использования JS. Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Современными средствами это достигается через CSS свойство [`aspect-ratio`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#aspect-ratio). Сделал по подобию из [ответа на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54927248/1548895)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: red;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>F</div>
  <div>G</div>
</div>
```

Раньше соотношение сторон достигалось через процентный `padding-bottom`.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.container div {
  background-color: red;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>F</div>
  <div>G</div>
</div>
```

---

### Ещё варианты

Также можно использовать `vmin` (или `vmax`) для строк и стоблцов. Это подойдёт если вы ведёте речь про
блоки, которые занимают большую часть экрана.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30vmin);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 30vmin);
}

.grid__item {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
</div>
```

Также возможно использовать `vw` и `vh` если нужна ширина в процентах от ширины или высоты окна браузера.

Ещё можно использовать фиксированные (`px`, `cm`, `mm`, `in`) или зависящие от размера шрифта (`em`, `rem`, `ex`, `pt`, `pc`) единицы для ширины и высоты колонок.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде похоже.

Дальше добавить медиа запросы — и делать что угодно.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 30vw 30vw 30vw;
  grid-template-rows: 30vw 30vw 30vw;
}

.item-1 {
  background: red;
}

.item-2 {
  background: green;
}

.item-3 {
  background: blue;
}

.item-4 {
  background: grey;
}

.item-5 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item item-1"></div>
  <div class="item item-2"></div>
  <div class="item item-3"></div>
  <div class="item item-4"></div>
  <div class="item item-5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: grid-template-columns:30vw 30vw 30vw - переназначает же 1fr 1fr 1fr.
Видимо, я не совсем корректно сформулировала вопрос, хотелось бы, чтобы высота принимала значение ширины. Но спасибо за идею.

Comment: вот так и переназначили мы т.е сделали vw=vh , но бывает ещё другие способы сделать 100% квадратный элемент